# Laravel 5.0 Get uploaded file path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm uploading a file through a form.

When I dump the file with `$request->file("slide")` it returns an UploadedFile object but it haven't a method to get the path to the temporal file.

How can I get it?

I need the path to modify the image with Intervention Image before saving it to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the code I found the solution. UploadedFile extends from File and File extends from SplFileInfo so I can use its methods to access the paths:

```
$object->getPath();
```

Answer (score 7):

You should try

```
$request->file('slide')->getPathName();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think, since it's also returning the filename.